# Convert an association from has_many to a has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two related models TripPlan and Place.

```
class TripPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :places
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trip_plan
end
```

There's a corresponding migration for the places table:

```
class CreatePlaces < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :places do |t|
      t.references :trip_plan, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

So each TripPlan can have several places and each Place belongs to a single trip plan. But now I need a has_one / belongs_to relation between these models. I modified TripPlan model as follows:

```
class TripPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :place
end
```

But now if I try `TripPlan.find(1).place.build` it throws an error:

```
undefined method 'build' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods you get with `has_one` are different

```
TripPlan.find(1).build_place
```

You'll also get the `create_place` method